# How to deploy Drools Flow and rules by my web application

Tags: drools-flow

I've just now started my new project. My project manager said that Drools is the new technology and we will include drools flow and rules and will integrate our web application with it.

How does one integrate Drools flows and rules to within a web-application?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what technologies you use. If, for example, you use Java+Maven+Spring, you first need to include Drools dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Define the application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
            http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring.xsd">


    <drools:kbase id="kbase1">
        <drools:resources>
            <drools:resource source="classpath:Sample.drl" />
        </drools:resources>
    </drools:kbase>

    <drools:ksession id="ksession1" type="stateful" kbase="kbase1" />

</beans>
```

Then you can inject `ksession1` as a bean.