# Configuring drools and maven and writing hello world application using them

Tags: java, maven, drools

I want to learn drools and maven can any one help me with the links for configuring drools and maven and writing a basic hello world example using them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should first read the manual, then try google it. There have also been questions like this asked before, for example: [How to deploy Drools Flow and rules by my web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141301/how-to-deploy-drools-flow-and-rules-by-my-web-application)

But anyways. This is how to integrate it if you use Maven and Spring:

you first need to include Drools dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Define the application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
            http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring.xsd">


    <drools:kbase id="kbase1">
        <drools:resources>
            <drools:resource source="classpath:Sample.drl" />
        </drools:resources>
    </drools:kbase>

    <drools:ksession id="ksession1" type="stateful" kbase="kbase1" />

</beans>
```

Then you can inject `ksession1` as a bean.

Answer (score 0):

Try google: First result for `Drools Maven Tutorial`: http://www.installationwiki.org/Set_Up_for_JBoss_Drools.

Note that Maven is a "build" tool (actually it's more) whereas Drools is a platform/library. So using Drools does normally not depend on Maven. You might thus want to get separate tutorials.

Comment: @Mike that's the problem with links, they can change over the course of time. The essence of that first sentence was "use google to look for tutorials". Here's the current first google result (as of 2013-11-29): http://www.mastertheboss.com/drools/drools-and-maven-example-project